# How to prove this argument with combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

[image]

I have an initial thought that the LHS should be equated to be the number of trees with n nodes such that 1 edge is marked on the left side but after that I am a bit lost

Comment: editted @BrianM.Scott

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the lefthand side is certainly the most obvious one, and it turns out to work fine. Suppose that we remove the marked edge; what’s left will be two trees, one with $a$ vertices, say, and the other with $b=n-a$ vertices; let’s see if we can use those trees to get the righthand side.

Turn it around. There are $\binom{n}a$ ways to pick $a$ of the $n$ labelled vertices, $T_a$ ways to make them the vertices of a labelled tree, and $T_b$ ways to make the remaining $b$ vertices into a labelled tree. There are $a$ ways to pick one vertex of the first tree and $b$ ways to pick one vertex of the second tree; we’ll join those vertices by an edge to form a labelled tree on the original $n$ vertices, that new edge being the marked one. Clearly there are

$$\sum_{a+b=n}ab\binom{n}aT_aT_b$$

ways to do this. I’ll leave one last step for you: do you see why we have to multiply this by $\frac12$?